# Convert track bike to geared

Tags: road-bike, gears, single-speed, conversion, road

Is there any way to convert a track bike to a geared bike? I have a track bike with only the rails for the wheel but I've moved out of the city and there are more hills where I am now living so would like to convert to gears if possible and rather than buy a new bike, save some cash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert single speed, steel framed, vintage track bike to geared](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/73418/convert-single-speed-steel-framed-vintage-track-bike-to-geared)

Comment: Any way of merging these answers. Lookslike there was a technical error and posted twice.

Comment: I don't actually think the answers should be merged, because the two answers are for slightly different questions. These answers are for track dropounts (rear horisontal dropouts), where are the answer to the other question is for horisontal dropouts (front sliding dropouts).

Comment: @abdnChap No, OP literally posted the same question twice. Look at the active list of questions and you’ll see.

Comment: I know, I saw them, there is 3 of them. what I am saying is that there is a diffrence in the questions, which lead to a difference in the answers. And it might be a good idea to have one for track bikes and one for horisontal dropout bikes. I read this question purely as track bike, whereas I read this https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/73418/convert-single-speed-steel-framed-vintage-track-bike-to-geared as horisontal dropout bikes. And, apart from internal gear hubs, they require different solutions.

Comment: It will almost surely be cheaper to buy another cheap used bike.

Comment: I tried to edit the question once. So I guess there are 2 the same, and one edited.  It was a technical issue. Editing were not saving and I had to refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal but is doable.

Biggest factor being the rear hub spacing.

If it's 120mm horisontal dropouts (the standard for track frames) then the best thing would be to get a 120mm internal geared hub such as the [Sturmey Archer S-RF5 5Spd Hub](https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/hubs-internal-hub-gear-brake/28-hole-sturmey-archer-srf5-5spd-hub/) (other available).

If, for any reason, it has 130/135mm rear dropouts (as found on jump bike and other single speed mtb frames), then you can use a horisontal dropout mech hanger, pic below:

[image]

I would really think twice before bending a 120mm dropout to accept 130mm wheel, depending on the frame age and material, this could be a **very** bad idea.

Another thing to consider is the gear cable, best thing would be use a complete outer running from the shifter to the rear and secure it along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Sturmey archer make 2, 3, 5 and 8speed hubs with a 120mm spacing for a track bike. The 2 sp requires no cables.

Older hubs are available in a 120 spacing to take a freewheel (up to 5sp?) and SunXCD makes a 120mm cassette hub. You would need a bolt on hanger to use either of these.

Hope that helps.